# customize edges in tikz-qtree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-qtree

Considering the following code,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{level 1/.style={level distance=26pt,sibling distance=10pt}}
  \tikzset{every tree node/.style={font=\fontsize{9pt}{8}\selectfont}}
  \tikzset{edge from parent/.style=
    {draw,edge from parent path={([shift={(0pt,0pt)}]\tikzparentnode) --      (\tikzchildnode)}}}
\Tree [.$=$ [.$+$
]
[.$-$
]
]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What modification do I need to do in order to start and end the edge a little more closer to the parent and child?

I have tried shifting it but its not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After [`the comment`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261404/customize-edges-in-tikz-qtree/261405?noredirect=1#comment626693_261405) clarifying the desired output, I wouldn't know how to do this with `tikz-qtree`, but I can offer you an alternative solution using the powerful [`forest`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/forest) package (the tree syntax is almost the same, but now you have additional customization features).

```
For example, you can set the parent anchor to be `west` for the left children and `east` for the right children (of course, more elaborate settings can be used, including for example shiftings):

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{forest}
for tree={
  s sep=20pt,
  math content,
  node options={inner xsep=3pt},
  if n=1
  {edge path={
    \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
      (!u.west) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
    }
  }
  { if n'=1
    {edge path={
     \noexpand\path[\forestoption{edge}]
       (!u.east) -- (.child anchor)\forestoption{edge label};
      }
    }
    {}
  }
}
[{=} 
  [+
    [\div
    ]
    [\ast
    ]
  ]
  [-
    [-
    ]
    [+
    ]
  ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I would like to perform a vertical shift only instead of both. It would be great if edge starts from the sides instead of from the bottom of the node.

Comment: Sorry if my question is not completely clear.

Comment: @Shahzad No problem. Thanks for the clarification. Please see my updated answer.